# Destroying and re-creating a matplotlib diagram implemented with FigureCanvasTkAgg

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am creating a Tkinter program where the user can input a value to create a shaded Venn Diagram using matplotlib-venn. Here is part of my code giving the instructions when the 'calculate' button is clicked after entering the formula, which plots a matplotlib diagram on a canvas on Tkinter.

```
def whenClicked():
    if str(selected.get()) == '3':
        plot1, v1 = configuration.createVenn3(formula.get())
        diagram = FigureCanvasTkAgg(plot1, master=window)
    if str(selected.get()) == '2':
        plot2, v2 = configuration.createVenn2(formula.get())
        diagram = FigureCanvasTkAgg(plot2, master=window)
    diagram.get_tk_widget().pack()
    diagram.draw()
```

The if-statement is to determine the number of circles in the Venn diagram, whether to make matplotlib-venn to plot diagram in a 2-circle or 3-circle system of matplotlib-venn. So literally, the order is to configure plot and v, and then define the diagram, which is object of canvas, and then plot the diagram on the canvas of Tkinter.

So the FigureCanvasTkAgg function will create a new variable called diagram and plot the configured diagram onto the GUI. However, here I am curious how I can configure Python to delete (destroy) the diagram and create (draw) a new one when the user enters a new formula and clicks the button again. Currently in the setup above, when I click the button again with a new formula, the new diagram will be plotted below the old diagram without destroying the old diagram, so it's not a good idea. I hope that the new diagram will be plotted at the exact same position of the old diagram.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer your question with some code without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but basically you should not recreate a new Figure / FigureCanvasTkAgg every time you are plotting something.

the basic idea is that you are creating a Figure + FigureCanvasTkAgg once during the initialization of your application, and probably create an Axes on that figure at the same time as well.

Then you should write your plotting function [so that it accept the axes as a parameter](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#coding-styles). That way, in the function that handles the button click, you can clear the content of the axes ([Axes.cla()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.cla.html?highlight=cla#matplotlib.axes.Axes.cla)), and draw a new diagram in the existing axes using your plotting function.